# Get full table with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to thank you for the help you have given me with Selenium Python.
In this same context, this is my last question (I hope).
I have a table in a web page that looks like this

| Image | Stars | Deductible 1 | Deductible 2 | Deductible 3 | Deductible 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Image1 | 3 | 125.824 | 148.205 | 176.276 | 270.097 |
| Image2 | 2 | 83.624 | 97.312 | 102.536 | 126.378 |
| Image3 | 5 | 69.411 | 79.682 | 88.267 | 125.100 |
| Image4 | 4 | 97.736 | 111.218 | 120.367 | 143.955 |

I get the information from each of these columns like this:

```
Header = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='matriz']//table/tbody//tr/th")

for my_Header in Header:
   print(my_Header.text)

Imagen = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='matriz']//table/tbody//tr[@class='filaMatriz']/td/img[@alt]")

for my_href in Imagen:
   print(my_href.get_attribute('alt'))
```

I get this:
**For alt in img:**

```
CHILENA CONSOLIDADA
LIBERTY SEGUROS GENERALES     
ZENIT SEGUROS GENERALES       
HDI
CHILENA CONSOLIDADA
```

```
print("Deductible \n")
V = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='matriz']//table/tbody//tr[@class='filaMatriz']/td/span")

for my_price in V:
    sleep(1)
    print(my_price.text)
```

I get this **For the price**

```
125.824
83.624
69.411
97.736
148.205
97.312
79.682
111.218
176.276
102.536
88.267
120.367
270.097
126.378
125.100
143.955
```

How can I make the match that each data belongs to the row of the table ? As well as the table?
I tried with this:

```
table_id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='matriz']")

for row in range(1, 11):
    rows = table_id.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr[" + str(row) + "]")
    for row_data in rows:
        col = row_data.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
        for i in range(len(col)):
            print(col[i].text)
```

And this is the full HTML for the table. thanks in advance.

```
<span id="matriz">
    <div class="matriz">
        <script id="j_id1102997597_32d04ecd" type="text/javascript">< !--
                setProductoSeleccionado = function() { PrimeFaces.ab({ s: "j_id1102997597_32d04ecd", f: "pasosForm", u: "formDialogCotiSelec botonera", pa: arguments[0] }); }
//--></script><input type="hidden" id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef8" name="j_id1102997597_32d04ef8" value="">
        <div class="column-table40">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="">Compañía</th>
                        <th class="star ">Calificación Clientes</th>
                        <th>Deducible 10 UF</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center "><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="CHILENA CONSOLIDADA           " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star ">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:4}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:10}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$125.824</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz filaSinResultado" style="display: none;">
                        <td class="text-center "><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:0:j_id1102997597_32d04c00:j_id415163359_1_4cfbfc60_1"
                                src="..."
                                alt="CHILENA CONSOLIDADA           " height="25px">
                        </td>
                        <td class="star ">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">Sin Producto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center "><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="LIBERTY SEGUROS GENERALES     " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star ">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:6}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:10}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$83.624</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz filaSinResultado" style="display: none;">
                        <td class="text-center "><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:1:j_id1102997597_32d04c00:j_id415163359_1_4cfbfc60_1"
                                src="..."
                                alt="LIBERTY SEGUROS GENERALES     " height="25px">
                        </td>
                        <td class="star ">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_0"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">Sin Producto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center "><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="ZENIT SEGUROS GENERALES       " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star ">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:7}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:10}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="ofta">$69.411</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center "><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="HDI" height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star ">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_4_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:10}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:10}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$97.736</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="column-table20">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidden-lg hidden-md ">Compañía</th>
                        <th class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">Calificación Clientes</th>
                        <th>Deducible 5 UF</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="CHILENA CONSOLIDADA           " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:4}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:5}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$148.205</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="LIBERTY SEGUROS GENERALES     " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:6}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:5}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$97.312</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="ZENIT SEGUROS GENERALES       " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:7}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:5}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="ofta">$79.682</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz filaSinResultado" style="display: none;">
                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:2:j_id1102997597_32d04c00:j_id415163359_1_4cfbfc60_1"
                                src="..."
                                alt="ZENIT SEGUROS GENERALES       " height="25px">
                        </td>
                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">Sin Producto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="HDI" height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_4_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:10}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:5}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$111.218</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="column-table20">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidden-lg hidden-md ">Compañía</th>
                        <th class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">Calificación Clientes</th>
                        <th>Deducible 3 UF</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="CHILENA CONSOLIDADA           " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:4}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:3}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$176.276</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz filaSinResultado" style="display: none;">
                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:0:j_id1102997597_32d04c00:j_id415163359_1_4cfbfc60_1"
                                src="..."
                                alt="CHILENA CONSOLIDADA           " height="25px">
                        </td>
                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">Sin Producto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="LIBERTY SEGUROS GENERALES     " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:6}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:3}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$102.536</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="ZENIT SEGUROS GENERALES       " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:7}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:3}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="ofta">$88.267</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="HDI" height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_4_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:10}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:3}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$120.367</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="column-table20">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidden-lg hidden-md ">Compañía</th>
                        <th class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">Calificación Clientes</th>
                        <th>Deducible 0 UF</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="CHILENA CONSOLIDADA           " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:4}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:0}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$270.097</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:1:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="LIBERTY SEGUROS GENERALES     " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:6}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:0}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$126.378</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:2:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="ZENIT SEGUROS GENERALES       " height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_3_5"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:7}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:0}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="ofta">$125.100</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr class="filaMatriz">

                        <td class="text-center hidden-lg hidden-md"><img
                                id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:3:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"
                                src="..."
                                alt="HDI" height="35px">
                        </td>

                        <td class="star hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <span id="estrellas" class="calificacion nota_4_0"></span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="precio"
                                    onclick="setProductoSeleccionado([{name:'codigoCompania', value:10}, {name:'codigoServicio', value:0}, {name:'codigoTipoProducto', value:600}])">
                            </div><span class="">$143.955</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        

    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: There are a lot of `alt="CHILENA CONSOLIDADA"` with `style="display: none;"`. It won't be that easy ;)